# Printing an inputted list of ASCII codes as a list of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, ascii, typeerror

I'm a complete newb programmer and am having trouble getting a user inputted list of ASCII codes to print as a list of characters:

```
ascii_code = [109, 121, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 105, 115,
             32, 106, 97, 109, 101, 115]

#ascii_code = input("Please input your ASCII code:")

character_list = list()
for x in ascii_code:
    character_list.append(chr(x))

print (character_list)

['m', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'j', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's']
```

as you can see, the program works when the ASCII list is predefined (in first line of code) but when I try to run an input such as:

- ascii_code = input("Please input your ASCII code:")
- ascii_code = int(input("Please input your ASCII code:"))
- ascii_code = eval(input("Please input your ASCII code:"))

I get either TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) or TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to type in during the `input` call?

Comment: A list of ASCII codes such as: 109, 121, 32, 110, 97,..etc

Comment: well you get a str from input so just deal with str... read up on split and strip perhaps? and then int whatever you got from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get from `input()` is either a tuple (python 2, so use `raw_input()` to get the correct behavior) or a string (python 3). I'll assume you're using Python 3 or will switch to using `raw_input` because `input` in Python 2 is just bad practice.

The result you get from the user is a comma-separated string. You need to break that string into parts, which you can do with `.split(',')`:

```
>>> s = raw_input('Enter ASCII codes:')
Enter ASCII codes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>>> s.split(',')
[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5']
```

However you'll notice that the numbers in the list are 1) strings, not ints, and 2) have spaces around them. We can fix this by looping over the numbers and using `.strip()` to remove whitespace and `int()` to convert the stripped string to a number which we can pass to `chr()`:

```
character_list = []
for p in s.split(','):
    character_list.append(chr(int(s.strip())))
```

...but it's more Pythonic to do this with a list comprehension:

```
character_list = [ chr(int(p.strip())) for p in s.split(',') ]
```

So your final code would end up as:

```
>>> s = raw_input('Enter ASCII codes: ')
Enter ASCII codes: 65, 66, 67
>>> character_list = [ chr(int(p.strip())) for p in s.split(',') ]
>>> print(character_list)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```